# How do I create Preference Attributes programmatically?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I want to create new [Preference Attributes](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/profile_and_preference_attributes/) via API.  Is this possible?  There does not seem to be any [documented interface](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/subscribers/subscriber-update.html) for doing so.

The email I intend to send has several areas of interest included in a single email.  The user can opt in or out of each area of interest via Preference Attributes manually or the software may determine them algorithmically and set them up for him.  The areas of interest are data driven and determined via database queries.

So, for instance, I may want to create Preference Attributes called "Math and Science" and another called "Reading and Writing", to determine if a given subscriber will get those topics in his weekly email.

Comment: Can you provide examples of the attributes you want to set?   Language, time zone, locale can be set programmatically, but I know you are unable to set a user's default dashboard.

Comment: @James added example description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Creating a Subscriber Attribute](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_subscriber_attribute/). There are many examples there across many languages.

Comment: Thanks! I never saw that because I was looking for the wrong words.  It is also available, though undocumented, in the Ruby FuelSDK: ```sdk = FuelSDK::ProfileAttribute.new
      sdk.authStub = @client
      sdk.props = {
        'Name' => new_name,
        'PropertyType' => 'boolean',
        'PropertyTypeSpecified' => true,
        'IsEditable' => true,
        'IsEditableSpecified' => true,
        'CustomerKey' => group_id,
        'IsCreatable' => true,
        'IsUpdatable' => true,
        'DefaultValue' => true
      }
      result = sdk.post
```